# Javascript file links not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four different files linked together.
Index.html - style.css - script.js - script2.js

script2.js contains a small test script to test and see if it all works, which it does.

index.html contains the following:

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <div id="container">
          <div id="message">
            <a id="animate" href="#">Transmit</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Now my script.js file contains this:

```
(function () {
    var $animate, $container, $message, $paragraph, MESSAGES, animate, initialise, scramble;
    MESSAGES = [];
    MESSAGES.push({
        delay: 0,
        text: 'Incoming transmission...'
    });
    MESSAGES.push({
        delay: 1200,
        text: 'You don\'t talk to anybody.'
    });
    MESSAGES.push({
        delay: 2200,
        text: 'You don\'t interact with anybody.'
    });
    MESSAGES.push({
        delay: 3600,
        text: 'Your whole sense of reality is, pretty warped...'
    });
    MESSAGES.push({
        delay: 5200,
        text: 'Does it bother you that we\'re not real?'
    });
    $container = $('#container');
    $message = $('#message');
    $animate = $('#animate');
    $paragraph = null;
    scramble = function (element, text, options) {
        var $element, addGlitch, character, defaults, ghostCharacter, ghostCharacters, ghostLength, ghostText, ghosts, glitchCharacter, glitchCharacters, glitchIndex, glitchLength, glitchProbability, glitchText, glitches, i, j, k, letter, object, order, output, parameters, ref, results, settings, shuffle, target, textCharacters, textLength, wrap;
        defaults = {
            probability: 0.2,
            glitches: '-|/\\',
            blank: '',
            duration: text.length * 40,
            ease: 'easeInOutQuad',
            delay: 0
        };
        $element = $(element);
        settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
        shuffle = function () {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        };
        wrap = function (text, classes) {
            return '<span class="' + classes + '">' + text + '</span>';
        };
        glitchText = settings.glitches;
        glitchCharacters = glitchText.split('');
        glitchLength = glitchCharacters.length;
        glitchProbability = settings.probability;
        glitches = function () {
            var j, len, results;
            results = [];
            for (j = 0, len = glitchCharacters.length; j < len; j++) {
                if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
                    break;
                }
                letter = glitchCharacters[j];
                results.push(wrap(letter, 'glitch'));
            }
            window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
            return results;
        }();
        ghostText = $element.text();
        ghostCharacters = ghostText.split('');
        ghostLength = ghostCharacters.length;
        ghosts = function () {
            var j, len, results;
            results = [];
            for (j = 0, len = ghostCharacters.length; j < len; j++) {
                if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(2)) {
                    break;
                }
                letter = ghostCharacters[j];
                results.push(wrap(letter, 'ghost'));
            }
            window.CP.exitedLoop(2);
            return results;
        }();
        textCharacters = text.split('');
        textLength = textCharacters.length;
        order = function () {
            results = [];
            for (var j = 0; 0 <= textLength ? j < textLength : j > textLength; 0 <= textLength ? j++ : j--) {
                if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(3)) {
                    break;
                }
                results.push(j);
            }
            window.CP.exitedLoop(3);
            return results;
        }.apply(this).sort(this.shuffle);
        output = [];
        for (i = k = 0, ref = textLength; 0 <= ref ? k < ref : k > ref; i = 0 <= ref ? ++k : --k) {
            if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(4)) {
                break;
            }
            glitchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (glitchLength - 1));
            glitchCharacter = glitches[glitchIndex];
            ghostCharacter = ghosts[i] || settings.blank;
            addGlitch = Math.random() < glitchProbability;
            character = addGlitch ? glitchCharacter : ghostCharacter;
            output.push(character);
        }
        window.CP.exitedLoop(4);
        object = { value: 0 };
        target = { value: 1 };
        parameters = {
            duration: settings.duration,
            ease: settings.ease,
            step: function () {
                var index, l, progress, ref1;
                progress = Math.floor(object.value * (textLength - 1));
                for (i = l = 0, ref1 = progress; 0 <= ref1 ? l <= ref1 : l >= ref1; i = 0 <= ref1 ? ++l : --l) {
                    if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(5)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    index = order[i];
                    output[index] = textCharacters[index];
                }
                window.CP.exitedLoop(5);
                return $element.html(output.join(''));
            },
            complete: function () {
                return $element.html(text);
            }
        };
        return $(object).delay(settings.delay).animate(target, parameters);
    };
    animate = function () {
        var data, element, index, j, len, options;
        for (index = j = 0, len = MESSAGES.length; j < len; index = ++j) {
            if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(6)) {
                break;
            }
            data = MESSAGES[index];
            element = $paragraph.get(index);
            element.innerText = '';
            options = { delay: data.delay };
            scramble(element, data.text, options);
        }
        window.CP.exitedLoop(6);
    };
    initialise = function () {
        var index, j, len, text;
        $animate.click(animate);
        for (index = j = 0, len = MESSAGES.length; j < len; index = ++j) {
            if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(7)) {
                break;
            }
            text = MESSAGES[index];
            $message.append('<p>');
        }
        window.CP.exitedLoop(7);
        $paragraph = $container.find('p');
        animate();
    };
    initialise();
}.call(this));
```

Which does not work. Why? I don't understand why one file works, yet the other doesn't...

Comment: Try to inspect element and see if `script.js` is loading or not. Perhaps your file path is incorrect? Try to `console.log()` to see up to what point the script works.

Comment: have you created folders as js for java script and css for style ??

Comment: What is `window.CP`?  I see you calling that, but I don't see it getting declared anywhere. If it is declared in your second script file, it won't work unless you defer executing your first script. What errors are in your console (if any)?

Comment: File path is correct.

As for the windows.CP thing, i'm unsure. Being honest this is from a codepen (All credit to owner, http://codepen.io/wagerfield/pen/wftcE) and im trying to see if I can make something of it. But I always run into this problem where nothing works.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to add commentary like "I'm still looking for help". That's considered an abuse of the fact that editing bumps a question to the front page.

Comment: If you must edit, edit to include what you mean by "which does not work". Do you mean there's an error in your console? Have you tried debugging it using your browser's debugger? Basically, read [ask] and make sure you've hit all of the points.

Answer (score 8):

Your script.js doesn't work because `window.CP` is undefined. `window.CP` is part of CodePen to prevent infinite loops from hanging your tab or browser.

Take the original coffee script (not the compiled one) from http://codepen.io/wagerfield/pen/wftcE and convert it to javascript using http://js2.coffee, and use that as your script.js

Here is the converted javascript (use it as your script.js):

```
var $animate, $container, $message, $paragraph, MESSAGES, animate, initialise, scramble;

MESSAGES = [];

MESSAGES.push({
  delay: 0,
  text: "Incoming transmission..."
});

MESSAGES.push({
  delay: 1200,
  text: "You don't talk to anybody."
});

MESSAGES.push({
  delay: 2200,
  text: "You don't interact with anybody."
});

MESSAGES.push({
  delay: 3600,
  text: "Your whole sense of reality is, pretty warped..."
});

MESSAGES.push({
  delay: 5200,
  text: "Does it bother you that we're not real?"
});

$container = $("#container");

$message = $("#message");

$animate = $("#animate");

$paragraph = null;

scramble = function(element, text, options) {
  var $element, addGlitch, character, defaults, ghostCharacter, ghostCharacters, ghostLength, ghostText, ghosts, glitchCharacter, glitchCharacters, glitchIndex, glitchLength, glitchProbability, glitchText, glitches, i, j, k, letter, object, order, output, parameters, ref, results, settings, shuffle, target, textCharacters, textLength, wrap;
  defaults = {
    probability: 0.2,
    glitches: '-|/\\',
    blank: '',
    duration: text.length * 40,
    ease: 'easeInOutQuad',
    delay: 0.0
  };
  $element = $(element);
  settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
  shuffle = function() {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  };
  wrap = function(text, classes) {
    return "<span class=\"" + classes + "\">" + text + "</span>";
  };
  glitchText = settings.glitches;
  glitchCharacters = glitchText.split('');
  glitchLength = glitchCharacters.length;
  glitchProbability = settings.probability;
  glitches = (function() {
    var j, len, results;
    results = [];
    for (j = 0, len = glitchCharacters.length; j < len; j++) {
      letter = glitchCharacters[j];
      results.push(wrap(letter, 'glitch'));
    }
    return results;
  })();
  ghostText = $element.text();
  ghostCharacters = ghostText.split('');
  ghostLength = ghostCharacters.length;
  ghosts = (function() {
    var j, len, results;
    results = [];
    for (j = 0, len = ghostCharacters.length; j < len; j++) {
      letter = ghostCharacters[j];
      results.push(wrap(letter, 'ghost'));
    }
    return results;
  })();
  textCharacters = text.split('');
  textLength = textCharacters.length;
  order = (function() {
    results = [];
    for (var j = 0; 0 <= textLength ? j < textLength : j > textLength; 0 <= textLength ? j++ : j--){ results.push(j); }
    return results;
  }).apply(this).sort(this.shuffle);
  output = [];
  for (i = k = 0, ref = textLength; 0 <= ref ? k < ref : k > ref; i = 0 <= ref ? ++k : --k) {
    glitchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (glitchLength - 1));
    glitchCharacter = glitches[glitchIndex];
    ghostCharacter = ghosts[i] || settings.blank;
    addGlitch = Math.random() < glitchProbability;
    character = addGlitch ? glitchCharacter : ghostCharacter;
    output.push(character);
  }
  object = {
    value: 0
  };
  target = {
    value: 1
  };
  parameters = {
    duration: settings.duration,
    ease: settings.ease,
    step: function() {
      var index, l, progress, ref1;
      progress = Math.floor(object.value * (textLength - 1));
      for (i = l = 0, ref1 = progress; 0 <= ref1 ? l <= ref1 : l >= ref1; i = 0 <= ref1 ? ++l : --l) {
        index = order[i];
        output[index] = textCharacters[index];
      }
      return $element.html(output.join(''));
    },
    complete: function() {
      return $element.html(text);
    }
  };
  return $(object).delay(settings.delay).animate(target, parameters);
};

animate = function() {
  var data, element, index, j, len, options;
  for (index = j = 0, len = MESSAGES.length; j < len; index = ++j) {
    data = MESSAGES[index];
    element = $paragraph.get(index);
    element.innerText = '';
    options = {
      delay: data.delay
    };
    scramble(element, data.text, options);
  }
};

initialise = function() {
  var index, j, len, text;
  $animate.click(animate);
  for (index = j = 0, len = MESSAGES.length; j < len; index = ++j) {
    text = MESSAGES[index];
    $message.append("<p>");
  }
  $paragraph = $container.find("p");
  animate();
};

initialise();

// ---
// generated by coffee-script 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 4):

So I had a buddy of mine running into the same issue but he wanted to use window.CP.shouldStopExecution.  So I inspected codepen's javascript files and found the file where it comes from.

You can save the contents below to a js file and then import it into your javascript script.  The window.CP function subset should completely work after that.

```html
"use strict";"object"!=typeof window.CP&&(window.CP={}),window.CP.PenTimer={programNoLongerBeingMonitored:!1,timeOfFirstCallToShouldStopLoop:0,_loopExits:{},_loopTimers:{},START_MONITORING_AFTER:2e3,STOP_ALL_MONITORING_TIMEOUT:5e3,MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT:2200,exitedLoop:function(o){this._loopExits[o]=!0},shouldStopLoop:function(o){if(this.programKilledSoStopMonitoring)return!0;if(this.programNoLongerBeingMonitored)return!1;if(this._loopExits[o])return!1;var t=this._getTime();if(0===this.timeOfFirstCallToShouldStopLoop)return this.timeOfFirstCallToShouldStopLoop=t,!1;var i=t-this.timeOfFirstCallToShouldStopLoop;if(i<this.START_MONITORING_AFTER)return!1;if(i>this.STOP_ALL_MONITORING_TIMEOUT)return this.programNoLongerBeingMonitored=!0,!1;try{this._checkOnInfiniteLoop(o,t)}catch(o){return this._sendErrorMessageToEditor(),this.programKilledSoStopMonitoring=!0,!0}return!1},_sendErrorMessageToEditor:function(){try{if(this._shouldPostMessage()){var o={action:"infinite-loop",line:this._findAroundLineNumber()};parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(o),"*")}else this._throwAnErrorToStopPen()}catch(o){this._throwAnErrorToStopPen()}},_shouldPostMessage:function(){return document.location.href.match(/boomerang/)},_throwAnErrorToStopPen:function(){throw"We found an infinite loop in your Pen. We've stopped the Pen from running. Please correct it or contact support@codepen.io."},_findAroundLineNumber:function(){var o=new Error,t=0;if(o.stack){var i=o.stack.match(/boomerang\S+:(\d+):\d+/);i&&(t=i[1])}return t},_checkOnInfiniteLoop:function(o,t){if(!this._loopTimers[o])return this._loopTimers[o]=t,!1;var i=t-this._loopTimers[o];if(i>this.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT)throw"Infinite Loop found on loop: "+o},_getTime:function(){return+new Date}},window.CP.shouldStopExecution=function(o){var t=window.CP.PenTimer.shouldStopLoop(o);return t===!0&&console.warn("[CodePen]: An infinite loop (or a loop taking too long) was detected, so we stopped its execution. Sorry!"),t},window.CP.exitedLoop=function(o){window.CP.PenTimer.exitedLoop(o)};
```

Comment: Oddly/surprisingly, I was getting that same error within CodePen itself, but copying this code to a new pen and [referencing it as an external `.js` resource](https://blog.codepen.io/2013/05/28/new-feature-use-pens-as-external-resources/) solved the problem.  Strange... but fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make it sure that the file path is correct.

Base in your code you include your javascript file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

So make it sure that your file index.html and script.js is in the same folder.

if it's not, try to include your javascript file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Please explain with folder structure.

Comment: Changed it so my files are set into folders, and tested, and works. Except only the test (script2.js) file works, and the css. The script.js file, the one I want to work, still doesn't.

Comment: @Warriorsfury May I know if your javascript file and css file is in different folder with your .html file? And please also upload your script2.js, so that we can check your script, because, maybe you are using function(){} in different script which is script.js and script2.js, that's why the other script is not working.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4d2012dfd7235ac497cfe1187b0cb874

the script2.js is the following: 

alert("Hello")

Sadly I haven't solved the problem...

Comment: try this <script type="text/javascript" src="../java/script.js"></script> if it's still not working, please try to change the folder name from "java" to "js"

Answer (score 0):

First of all check out in browser with Inspect Element(F12) -> Network or console which path you are getting for script.js . Use ~ for set path. ~ will set root of your folder structure.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Set folder name from Root/script.js"></script>
```

if your file is place in Assets -> Script folder then your path will be "~/Assets/Script/script.js"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Assets/Script/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: The path for the file is completely fine and working.